# How to make toString method within object?

Tags: java, tostring

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

  int number;
  String suit;

  public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;

      @Override
        public String toString() {

          String[] high = {
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King"
          };

            String type;

            if (number < 10) {
              return String.valueOf(this.number) + " of " + this.suit;
            }
            else {
              return high[this.number-10] + " of " + this.suit;
            }

            //return suit + " of " + type;

          //return String.valueOf(number) + " of " + suit;
        }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] suit = {
      "Clubs",
      "Diamonds",
      "Spades",
      "Hearts"
    };

    // String[] high = {
    //   "Jack",
    //   "Queen",
    //   "King"
    // };

    ArrayList<Card> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

        deckOfCards.add(new Card (i+1, suit[j]));
            currentCard.toString();
      }
    }



    // @Override
    // public String toString(Card card) {
    //
    //   this.suit = suit;
    //   this.number = number;
    //
    //   String type;
    //
    //   if (number < 10) {
    //     type = Integer.toString(number);
    //   }
    //   else {
    //     type = high[i-number];
    //   }
    //
    //   return suit + " of " + type;
    //   }

    // currentCard.toString();

  }
}
```

Everything works except the toString method within the Card class. Not 100% sure what the problem is, error message is

Card.java:13: error: ';' expected
        public String toString() {

Any help is appreciated Thank You

Comment: Your constructor contain your method toString. Move this method out and everything will be fine. If you are not sure about the structure, please refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: if one of these answers was helpful to you, please accept it and/or upvote.

Comment: Pls use a basic IDE like eclipse and make use of the `ctrl+1` and `ctrl+space` functions, they can solve most of your problems in no time.

Answer (score 3):

Your `toString()` method is inside your `Card(int number, String suite)` constructor. Move it out.

Answer (score 1):

the `String method` is inside of the constructor of the class Cards, move it outside so you can use it, and so  you can have a valid Card `constr`.

Answer (score 0):

Place the toString outside of your constructor.

```
 public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
}
 @Override
 public String toString() {

          String[] high = {
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King"
          };

            String type;

            if (number < 10) {
              return String.valueOf(this.number) + " of " + this.suit;
            }
            else {
              return high[this.number-10] + " of " + this.suit;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toString() method is inside your constructor;

here is the corrected code

```
public class Card {

  int number;
  String suit;

  public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }


      @Override
        public String toString() {

          String[] high = {
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King"
          };

            String type;

            if (number < 10) {
              return String.valueOf(this.number) + " of " + this.suit;
            }
            else {
              return high[this.number-10] + " of " + this.suit;
            }

            //return suit + " of " + type;

          //return String.valueOf(number) + " of " + suit;
        }

// your main starts from here..
```

dont forget to format if youre in eclipse ctrl+shift+f